# Apache Server CPU Spikes what will be the root cause?

Tags: web-server, apache-2.4, troubleshooting

We have a CMS Server which runs with apache Server. During night time around 7 to 11 PM the cpu spikes and after some time it comes down automatically.

I tried different troubleshooting methods like reloading and restarting the apache server. Is there any permanent solution or what could be the root cause for this?

Comment: What kind/brand/make of CMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As we are all aware Apache is dealing with hardware resource(cpu+ram)...if you are enough HW and proper tuning of apache will lead the cpu spike issues.

These are below points can help you
-->Is this your CMS+Apache running on the same machine? if yes please capture Thread Dumps and  Heap Dump if required.
-->CPU spike is dependent on how load is on the application level.
-->As you said it's some particular time cpu spike issue,then you have to think out of the box ex: Network,DB etc..

Thanks,
Amarnath Polu